How to create subsets of data with different fractions of samples without replacement?
I have a dataset and from this wish to create random samples without replacement and create a dataset for each:
"90%sampled", "90%sampled","80%sampled","70%sampled","60%sampled","50%sampled"
Please could someone advise how to do this using a loop function? This did not work.
for(i in 0:5){
    leave.out.percentage <- (i)/10
    data.SAMPLEDi <- dat %>% sample_frac(1-leave.out.percentage) # sample
} 


Please share a reproducible example of the problem, including data. That is the only way you can get help on Stack Overflow!

Simply do this

library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)  
dat <- data.frame(
  id = 1:100,
  value = rnorm(100)
)

percentages <- c(0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5)

sampled_datasets <- list()

for (p in percentages) {
  sampled_data <- dat %>% 
    sample_frac(p) 
  sampled_datasets[[paste0(as.integer(p * 100), "%sampled")]] <- sampled_data
}


for (name in names(sampled_datasets)) {
  assign(name, sampled_datasets[[name]])
}

which will produce your samples.

One option is purrr::walk instead of loop:
library(tidyverse)
my_prop <- c(0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5)

walk(
  seq_along(my_prop), 
  \(x) assign(
    envir = .GlobalEnv,
    paste0("my_sample_", x), 
    slice_sample(starwars, prop = my_prop[x])))

Output:
> nrow(starwars)
[1] 87

> map_int(mget(ls(pattern = "my_sample")), nrow)
my_sample_1 my_sample_2 my_sample_3 my_sample_4 my_sample_5 my_sample_6 
         78          78          69          60          52          43

Created on 2024-05-21 with reprex v2.1.0

## Assuming your data is in a data frame called `dat`
p <- c(0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5)

# Make each of your sampled data sets an element of the list data.SAMPLED
data.SAMPLED <- lapply(p, \(p) dplyr::sample_frac(dat, p))

For example:
dat <- sleep

p <- c(0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5)
data.SAMPLED <- lapply(p, \(p) dplyr::sample_frac(dat, p))

produces:
> data.SAMPLED

[[1]]
   extra group ID
1    0.8     1  8
2    5.5     2  7
3    1.9     2  1
4    0.8     2  2
5    1.6     2  8
6    3.4     1  6
7    2.0     1 10
8    3.4     2 10
9    0.0     1  9
10   0.7     1  1
11   3.7     1  7
12  -0.1     2  5
13  -0.1     1  5
14  -1.6     1  2
15  -1.2     1  4
16   4.6     2  9
17   0.1     2  4
18  -0.2     1  3

[[2]]
   extra group ID
1    0.8     1  8
2    0.7     1  1
3    4.6     2  9
4    0.1     2  4
5    1.9     2  1
6    0.8     2  2
7    3.4     1  6
8    2.0     1 10
9    4.4     2  6
10  -1.2     1  4
11   5.5     2  7
12  -0.2     1  3
13   3.7     1  7
14  -0.1     2  5
15   0.0     1  9
16  -1.6     1  2

[[3]]
   extra group ID
1    1.6     2  8
2    5.5     2  7
3    1.9     2  1
4    1.1     2  3
5    3.4     1  6
6    0.7     1  1
7    2.0     1 10
8   -0.1     2  5
9   -0.2     1  3
10  -1.2     1  4
11   4.4     2  6
12   0.1     2  4
13   0.8     1  8
14   4.6     2  9

[[4]]
   extra group ID
1    3.4     2 10
2    2.0     1 10
3    0.0     1  9
4    0.8     1  8
5   -1.2     1  4
6   -0.1     1  5
7    0.8     2  2
8    4.6     2  9
9    1.9     2  1
10  -0.1     2  5
11   0.1     2  4
12   1.6     2  8

[[5]]
   extra group ID
1    0.1     2  4
2    3.4     2 10
3    0.8     2  2
4   -0.2     1  3
5    2.0     1 10
6    1.1     2  3
7    3.7     1  7
8   -0.1     2  5
9    5.5     2  7
10  -1.6     1  2

